# Does the APNs authentication key work for all my app ids?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have one app and it's dev version.

- I have 2 Firebase projects: myApp and myApp-dev.
- I have 2 Apple App ID: myApp and myApp-dev.
- I have 1 Authentication key that I've uploaded to both of my firebase projects.

Is this right? Does one auth key work for all my apps?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I see that the keys can be used for multiple apps.
Still I'm having problems since I changed to the new .p8 type of key.

[image: iOS Certificates page]

Answer (score 24):

"**One APNS to rule them all**, One APNS to find them, One APNS to bring them all and in the darkness bind them."

[image: Be careful while using it !!!]

The answer is unfortunately **yes**. You can use one APNS for all of your IOS apps. **Be careful** while using it !

Comment: why it's unfortunate?

Comment: In my (friend) case: you can mistakenly send a push notification message to the production environment while you are thinking to send a message to your test application. this is why it is dangerous and unfortunate. @WeirdElfB0y

Answer (score 7):

The Answer is Yes. **One key is used for all of your apps.**
[image: iOS Certificates page]